# pandas groupby named aggregation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to upgrade pandas to version 1 from 0.25.3
given a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd


d = {'group': [1, 2, 2], 'value': [3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How should I migrate the following groupby

```
aggregation = {
    "value": {
        "min": lambda x: x.min(skipna=True),
    }
}
grouped = (
    df[["group", "value"]]
        .groupby(["group"], as_index=False)
        .agg(aggregation)
)
```

```
grouped = (
    df[["group", "value"]]
        .groupby(["group"], as_index=False)
        .agg(min=pd.NamedAgg(column='value', aggfunc='min'))
)
```

That doesn't work as expected because the group column is missing. See the output of `grouped.columns`

> MultiIndex([('group',    ''),
>               ('value', 'min')],
>              )

vs

> Index(['min'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to include the `group` column too. It seems like  `as_index=False` doesn't work anymore

```
grouped = (
    df[["group", "value"]]
        .groupby(["group"], as_index=True)
        .agg(
            group=NamedAgg(column='group', aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[0]),
            min=pd.NamedAgg(column='value', aggfunc='min')
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in pandas 1.0. I had raised the issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32240).
Upgrade to pandas 1.1 and your code will start working.
The simplest fix without upgrade would be to separate aggregation and renaming.

```
aggregation = {
    "value": lambda x: x.min(skipna=True),
    
}
grouped = (
    df[["group", "value"]]
        .groupby(["group"], as_index=False)
        .agg(aggregation)
)
grouped.rename(columns={'value':'min'}, inplace=True)
```